# WordPress Plugin to fix rotation problem on iPhone videos

Tags: video, wordpress

I am recording videos from my iPhone 4s and using the plugin [Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator (v4.5.5)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-embed-thumbnail-generator/) to encode HTML5-compliant video formats from said videos once I upload them to WordPress (v4.1.5). The problem is - the videos sometimes appear sideways or upside-down on my site. This seems to be a common iPhone problem. I have had a similar problem with images captured from my iPhone, and I fixed it using the [Image Rotation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/) plugin. Is there a way (another plugin?) to automatically fix this video orientation / rotation problem when I upload videos to WordPress? I'd prefer something that will not require me to upload to YouTube or Vimeo or the like and grab an embed code from there, but something that will just convert, properly orient, and insert the embed code of the video for me from within WordPress.